# Create the opposite transition with a push view controller from left to right

Tags: swift, xcode

```
 let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let resultViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "startQuiz") as! StartQuizsViewController
        resultViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.show(resultViewController, sender: nil)
```

I have this code in which the controller transitions from right to left. How can I go back from left to right. The opposite effect like you are going backwards or hitting the back button. This is a show transition and it needs to be that for the tabbar.

Comment: See [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218) for correct way to customize transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably will want to make a "custom" transition and add it to the view window's layer right before you show the view controller.  It's important that you do this first, as if you wait until after you show the view controller to add the transition, nothing will happen.  Here's some example code that should do what you want:

```swift
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.4
transition.type = .push
transition.subtype = .fromLeft
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
self.show(resultViewController, sender: nil)
```

The transition type is push, like normal, but in the subtype I changed the direction to match your opposite effect.  You can play around with different subtypes to see different directions of the transition.

Comment: just one more thing, is there a way to stop the bouncing when transiting.

Comment: Trying different timing functions would probably change that - you might want `.linear` instead of `.easeInEaseOut`.  If that doesn't work, let me know.